# python 2.7: hex netmask to dotted decimal

Tags: python-2.7

output of ifconfig command on aix gives the netmask in hex.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> import os
>>> import re
>>> import socket
>>> ifconfig_output = subprocess.check_output(['/usr/sbin/ifconfig', '-a']).decode()
>>> result = re.findall(r'[\s]+inet ([\d\.]+) netmask ([\w.]+) broadcast ([\d\.]+)', ifconfig_output, re.S | re.M)
>>> print(result)
[(u'172.17.14.50', u'0xfffff800', u'172.17.15.255'), (u'172.16.156.50', u'0xffffc000', u'172.16.191.255'), (u'172.16.12.10', u'0xfffffe00', u'172.16.13.255'), (u'127.0.0.1', u'0xff000000', u'127.255.255.255')]
```

i tried this but this does not let me use the 0x prefix.

```
>>> s = '0xffffc000'
>>> print '.'.join(str(int(i, 16)) for i in ([s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <genexpr>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '0x'
>>> s = 'ffffc000'
>>> print '.'.join(str(int(i, 16)) for i in ([s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]))
255.255.192.0
>>>
```

so how to convert the netmask to dotted decimal notation only with standard lib (no modules)? remember that this is python 2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is bit-shifting and mask:

```
s = int('0xffffc000', 16)
mask = 0x000000ff

print(".".join(map(str, [mask & (s >> 24), mask & (s >> 16), mask & (s >> 8), mask & s])))
```

Output:

```
255.255.192.0
```

EDIT: Using your method, just start with `2` in `range()` instead of `0`

```
range(2, len(s), 2)
```